# Rails generic controller and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been looking at [Administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) source code and would like to know if it's a good practice or not the use of a generic controller and what implications it would have, like code complexity, performance degradation, etc.

Sometime ago, there was a gem [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) that provide this feature, but since Rails 3.0 or 3.1 has been said we no longer need them.

So, since I have some very simple models (with only two or three fields) I could create a generic view and controller to manipulate them and save a lot of lines of "duplicated" code. Although I'm afraid, by avoiding repetition I could be creating another monster.

I've been looking for a Rails way to do this, but failed, so I would thanks some advice.

Note: **I'm not looking to implement or use an admin dashboard, but use in my application instead**

Answer (score 0):

All Rails admin-panel implementations will make you hurt when you will try to make something more complex than stupid simple CRUD-application. I recomend you not to use such solutions. I had experiece in usage three different Rails's admin-panels and all of them had bad design and a lot of limitations. They are hard to mantain and extend their functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm not looking for using or create an admin panel, just use inside my app.